# button 2 text transition

Tags: wpf, silverlight

It is possible to have 2 text's on a wpf Button?

**Button 1**
[image]

```
 <Button>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
       <TextBlock FontSize="8" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Secondary</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>Primary</TextBlock>
   </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

I have another button

**Button2**

```
<Button>Toggle Text</Button>
```

When this button click's I want to change (toggle) the text  on first button.
Is this possible with `WPF` ?

```
 private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var temp = Primary.Text;

            Primary.Text = Secondary.Text;
            Secondary.Text = temp;

        }
```

[image]

Comment: its not clear what exactly you want? you want to show 2 text same time or you want to switch between 2 texts?

Comment: @N.J I want to show the 2 texts the same time like in image. When I click another button I want to change the text's, Primary and Secondary. ie make the secondary text larger and primary smaller (with a transition if possible)

Comment: are you following mvvm ?

Comment: he wants two text as in the picture in ONE BUTTON (perhaps)

Comment: @Muds yes I plan to implement mvvm, but for now I have only XAML code.

Comment: can you show us what all have you tried till now ? coz I still am not clear about exactly what are you looking for ..

you have 2 buttons, so if I press button1 you change text of button2 from Primary to Secondary and then  when you press button 2 text changes back to primary

is it ?

Comment: @Muds I added more info on question.

Comment: have you tried doing that in code behind by changing text in click handler ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use style and trigger together

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="98" Margin="119,83,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="327" x:Name="B">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Width="300" Height="50">
                                <TextBlock Text="secondary" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="Primary" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="22" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Switch,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Width="300" Height="50">
                                        <TextBlock Text="primary" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="secondary" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="22" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>

        </Button.Style>
    </Button>

<Button Content="TestBuuton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="66" Margin="336,330,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222" Command="{Binding TestCommand}" />
```

and in you viewview model you can switch the value like this

```
    RelayCommand test;
    public RelayCommand TestCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (test == null)
            {
                test = new RelayCommand(p => execute(p));
            }
            return test;
        }
    }


void execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (Switch)
        {
            Switch = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Switch = true;
        }
        RaisePropertyChanged("Switch");
    }
```

[image]
 after click 
[image]

i hope this is you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

XAML Code:

```
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="MainButton" Height="70" Width="213" Click="MainButton_Click" >
        <Grid Height="{Binding ElementName=MainButton, Path=ActualHeight}" Width="{Binding ElementName=MainButton, Path=ActualWidth}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>                    
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>                
            <TextBlock x:Name="TextOne" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="10 0">Primary</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="TextTwo" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Secondary</TextBlock>
        </Grid>            
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

C# Code-behind:

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string aux = TextOne.Text;

        TextOne.Text = TextTwo.Text;
        TextTwo.Text = aux;
    }
```

In the above example i used an ugly button, but its up to you to make it more beautifull. It is also NOT following MVVM pattern. When you feel ready to refactor it to MVVM, just use a Command inspite of the Click event, take off the "X:Names" and take the button texts from variables within your code.

Hope that helps.